# Path in graphics in C

Tags: turbo-c, bgi

I had been using graphics.h in my program for a while. I was facing problem in the path but I later resolved it. Now, I typed the wrong path in the `initigraph()` function but the program still worked. How is it possible?

Code1:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] ="vyfm";
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, a);

    line(100,100, 200, 200);

    getch();
    closegraph();

    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] ="C:\\TC\\BGI";
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, a);

    line(100,100, 200, 200);

    getch();
    closegraph();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My GOSH!!!  This is an *ANCIENT* Turbo C API.  The C++ language (to say nothing of computing in general) has changed a lot since then...  As to your question: `initgraph()` initializes the graphics system, and loads some runtime files from the BG (Borland Graphics) directory.  I guess your exe just didn't need any of those runtime files ;)

Comment: I am using codeblocks

Comment: But how is it posiible that the initgraph function doesn't requires any directory?

Comment: @KeshavSaraf `C:\\TC\\BGI` is clearly Turbo C, ... BGI works only under MS-DOS so if you're really have CodeBlocks what BGI an OS you got or targeting? That might answer your question as different version of BGI might handle the parameters differently. IIRC WinBGI has different header so you have something else... `graphics.h` is meaningless as almost all gfx engine has such file ... your code is clearly ancient BGI

Comment: You asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379061).  SAD AND UNFORTUNATE FACT: even if your program does something "wrong" ... you *WON'T* (necessarily) get a compile error, and it *MIGHT NOT* even fail at runtime (at least not at first).  It might "appear" to work. Those are the *WORST* kinds of bugs - the ones your customer finds, before you do :(  Always beware "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 0):

If you say that you are using codeblocks, be careful about compiling the code then run it. If you just use the "run" command in codeblocks it will just run your last exe, even if you current file is modified. The exe will be modified when you successfully compile your code. In this case your code should compile, but I think you missed this step.

Comment: I always use build and run option.